# Unable to access laravel 5.5 API route using Postman software

Tags: php, laravel, rest

My api.php route is

```
Route::get('/allposts','PostController@index');
```

Controller function is and working with web.php Route file

```
public function index()
{
    $posts= Post::all();
    return PostResource::collection($posts);
}
```

my Resource is toArray function is

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

Postman link using GET are
"queuetest.com/api/allposts"
"http://queuetest.com/api/allposts"
both are not working
and getting Result in both Post man and browser: Sorry the page your looking for could not be found

Comment: check w/ command: php artisan route:list   The output to see if you're messing up with routes.... your api route  /api/allposts should be in the list with method GET   Also attempt a php artisan route:clear just in case you cached the routes and maybe it's not getting your changes....

Answer (score 0):

Do you get something other than the `Sorry the page you're looking for could not be found` message when you do `var_dump('test');die();` in your index method as the first line.

Edit: try to remove then `/` before `/allPosts`

Another edit: check in your `RouteServiceProvider` if the `mapApiRoutes` prefix is set to `'api'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default route configuration that comes out of the box, you should place your route in `routes/api.php` if you want to access it in the `/api` namespace. Right now, the route should be accessible from http://queuetest.com/allposts.

This behavior can be configured in `App\Providers\RouteServiceProviders.php`. If you have a modified route configuration, there are numerous things that could cause this behaviour, and it is impossible to locate the problem without seeing more code.

Comment: Thanks Emil for response: Actually it is working in the default configuration means when i define route in the web.php route file. But when i define route in the api.php file shows me the subject error. how can i define route in api.php file ?

Comment: The same way you would add it in the web.php file